# Is the product of three non-square matrices possibly invertible if they produce a square matrix?

Tags: matrices, inverse

My question is if it is possible that the product of 3 non-square matrices is invertible if this product is a square matrix. 
e.g.

$A=2\times3, B = 3 \times 4, C = 4 \times 2$

and

$D=ABC$ then $D= 2\times2$ Can D be invertible?

Thanks!

Daniel

Comment: What you get at the end is a square matrix. So it could be invertible, as long as $\text{Det}\ D \neq 0$.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you get at the end is a square matrix.

So it can be invertible, as long as $\text{Det}\ D \neq 0$

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary that each of the matrices has rank at least 2. They don't need to have full rank. Here is an example:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0
\end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0&1\\
0&0\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Why those matrices: we need each of the three matrices to be full rank, and each of those is the easiest example with the maximum number of linearly independent columns.